# Deploying a production build of React app to Google App Engine: Service worker registration fails

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, deployment, service-worker

After building a **production build** of React application and following instructions on deploying it to Google's App Engine I'm having problems with service worker registration in all browsers.

I tried different configurations in `app.yaml` with the latest one being:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs8
# [END runtime]

# [START handlers]
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: build

  - url: /service-worker.js
    static_files: build/service-worker.js
    upload: build/service-worker.js
    secure: always
# [END handlers]
```

The error is logged in Firefox as

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: "The operation is insecure." serviceWorker.js:97:6

Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope ‘https://xxx.appspot.com/’: Bad Content-Type of ‘text/plain’ received for script ‘https://xxx.appspot.com/service-worker.js’.  Must be a JavaScript MIME type.
```

..and Chrome

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
serviceWorker.js:97 Error during service worker registration: DOMException
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.js:97
Promise.catch (async)
tn @ serviceWorker.js:96
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.js:51
load (async)
(anonymous) @ serviceWorker.js:34
429 @ index.js:25
p @ (index):1
276 @ stylesheet.js:47
p @ (index):1
i @ (index):1
e @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ main.609507e8.chunk.js:1
```

I didn't change the default service worker registration/configuration as there was no need for that. It's being registered in `index.js`. There are no problems with the registration when the production build is served locally.

```
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.register();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that some .js files including the service-worker and package-manifest were served in a plain `text` mime type, not `application/javascript`.

Targeting particular routes with regex patterns I managed to overwrite default settings and serve files in correct mime, one of which is `/service-worker.js` since it is requested in the registration process.

Here is the final `app.yaml`

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
# [END runtime]

# [START handlers]
handlers:
  - url: '/service-worker.js'
    secure: always
    static_files: build/service-worker.js
    upload: build/service-worker.js
    mime_type: application/javascript

  - url: /(precache-manifest.*)$
    secure: always
    mime_type: application/javascript
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(precache-manifest.*)$

  - url: /(.*\.js)$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.js$
    mime_type: application/javascript

  - url: /(.*\.(css|map|png|jpg|svg|ico|json|txt|woff))$
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(css|map|png|jpg|svg|ico|json|txt|woff)$

  - url: '/(.*)'
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
# [END handlers]
```

Answer (score 1):

Displaimer: not a nodejs user, answer based on docs only.

Since you're using the `handlers` section to specify static resources in your `app.yaml` file then you need to also add one with `script: auto`. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) (emphasis mine):

> **script**
>
> Optional. Specifies that requests to the specific handler should
>   target your app. The only accepted value for the `script` element is
>   `auto` because all traffic is served using the entrypoint command.
>   **In order to use static handlers, at least one of your handlers must contain the line `script: auto` to deploy successfully.**
>
> ```
> handlers:
> - url: /images
>   static_dir: static/images
>
> - url: /.*
>   secure: always
>   redirect_http_response_code: 301
>   script: auto
> ```

Side note: you have 2 handlers for the `/` pattern, the 2nd one will never be matched/hit, you'll always return `build/index.html` for it.

Comment: `- url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto`

Your comment got me into the documentation but I still didn't find a solution. The problem is that my-url/service-worker.js is served as text and not application/javascript.

`- url: /service-worker.js
    static_files: build/service-worker.js
    upload: build/service-worker.js
    mime_type: application/javascript
    secure: always`