# Angular Project Mime Type Errors on GCloud only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, angular-cli, gcloud

This has all happened out of the blue despite the deployment pipeline being fine for months.

I deploy my app using `google app cloud deploy` which takes the complied "dist" folder and puts it in the google container.

When I browse to the page I get:

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

The error comes from the polyfills. I have looked at my tsconfig.json and tried changing from ES5 to something else but the problem persists.

Googling the error has not yielded much help. I don't know if this is a bug that suddenly came about on the google side, or if my angular project is no longer compatible with the browser. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi OP, you might be referring to `gcloud app deploy` and you are deploying your app to App Engine. I suggest specifying the `mime_type` on your Javascript handlers as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959478/deploying-a-production-build-of-react-app-to-google-app-engine-service-worker-r). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Typo in my command above, your right... I actually deployed the exact same app to a different app container that I set up and it worked so its something to do with google cloud. Maybe I should switch to AWS