# ReactDom.render is DOMException: The operation is insecure in <iframe>?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, domexception

I am getting this error *DOMException: The operation is insecure.* and the whole thing seems to start at this simple **init code**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './src/app/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

It only happens in an `<iframe src="... - my locally served page with React - ...">` and only in Firefox (*104*).

The JavaScript files are [served with the following headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968130/2092322):

```
Content-Security-Policy:    default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'
Content-Type:   application/javascript
```

Any help is appreciated, I am out of ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was an access to `localStorage`.

Users might allow third party cookies in Firefox or - **in our case** - we can omit get/set of cookies for the URLs, which can be used in `<iframe>`s.

So we do location/path checking.

So this approach is interesting for cases, in which you can somehow detect that your app runs in an iframe **and** you can omit the usage of *localStorage*, *sessionStorage* and relatives.